# How to change date in database

Tags: mysql, database, date

In my Mysql database, i have a set of date.
How can I increase for each and every date in my database by 3 years ?

For example the current date is :
2 January 2001

I want the date to be increased by three years: 
2 January 2004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this -

```
UPDATE TABLE set fieldname =  DATE_ADD( fieldname, INTERVAL 3 YEAR )
```

For more information and play part with `dates` you can check this link :-

[function_date-add](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

Working Fiddle -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9c669/1

**EDIT**

This solution updates date type is **VARCHAR** and structure of date like - `2 January 2001`

It will update date to `2 January 2004` by the interval of `3`

Although the best way to handle date is use date DATATYPEs(ex timestamp, datetime etc) instead of saving it in `VARCHAR`s

Tested code --

```
UPDATE date 
SET `varchardate`= DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(  str_to_date(`varchardate`, '%d %M %Y'), INTERVAL 3 YEAR ) , '%d %M %Y')
```

Comment: @user1852728 I tested this before pasting it here...let me create a fiddle for you then

Comment: @user1852728 what is the fieldname data type in your case ?? mine is DATETIME

Comment: I forgot, the datatype is VARCHAR

Comment: @ton1c he is having varchar datatype so I believe he need to use str_to_date() and then again format the date using DATE_FORMAT() ..or a better version by storing the dates in another column and then checking..but he the one actually who have to choose the path :)

Comment: yup in my database its 2 January 2001. I'm using jquery datepicker

Comment: Or better he could supply the table and some data example

Comment: @swapnesh Im willing to learn on how to do this, could you help me.

Comment: @user1852728 sure I will ..give me 10 min :)

Comment: @user1852728 just fill up the column once again with the data and test..although i tested it twice :)

Answer (score 0):

Check date_add function, it should do the thing -http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

Below query is to update the date column and also changed to date format.

```
update date1 set dates = 
DATE_ADD( (str_to_date(concat( 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( dates,  ' ', 1 ),'-',
Substring(SUBSTRING_INDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX( dates,  ' ', 2 ) ,  ' ', -1 ),1,3) ,
'-', 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( dates,  ' ', -1 )),'%d-%M-%Y')), INTERVAL 3 YEAR )
```

OR

The second query is simply update the year by 3.

```
update date1 set dates = 
concat( SUBSTRING_INDEX( dates,  ' ', 2 )  ,  ' ', 
(SUBSTRING_INDEX( dates,  ' ', -1 ) +3) )
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cd8ff/1)